# Can I Intercept Reset button on my computer?

Tags: reset

Basically, is there a way to programmatically intercept CPU RESET, at any level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This button physically affects (galvanical "OR" with output of "reset" chip ?) the "Power Good" signal of the power supply, and routed through all possible boards being signal number 1 of every square inch of motherboard and peripherals. It lets thousands of ASIC/FPGA and analog  hardware designers sleep well. Do not disturb their peace of mind!

Comment: Only a theoretical remark: This might be relevant for PCs but not for other (embedded) devices, e.g. Palm Treo or the Apple IPhone/Ipod. These devices must be resetable without a reset button, because they just don't have one. There is no power on the reset pin via a button! It should be possible to change this by embedding it's own operating system wich changes this. Anyway: Why would you want to brick your device by disabling reset?

Comment: @dz.: On the Palm series devices, there was a hardware reset button.  As for the PC, historically the only way 80286-machines could return to DOS-compatible operation after accessing memory beyond address 0x0FFFFF was to reset the CPU, so the BIOS reset vector would check if certain bits were set and if so, continue earlier operations rather than performing a normal startup.  I would guess that a reset-button push would reset a latch the BIOS could use to distinguish reset-during-operation from startup reset, but I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty certain the answer is no... or else it would defeat the purpose ... wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. As far as i know reset is even a PIN on your CPU which is activated when you press the reset button. But on non PC platforms this might be different, e.g. the IPod Nano has no reset button.

Answer (score 0):

It's doubtful that anyone's designed a motherboard which lets you do this.

A reset would be a hardware interrupt, not possible to circumvent with software.

Answer (score 0):

It's hardware based, not software based. So you can't do much with software, no.